# How to get ViewResult as a string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do you get a ViewResult as a string?
For example, when a user makes a webrequest, i can return a page like this:

```
return View("/helloworld");
```

But i want to get it as a string and do something with it, for example:

```
string webpage = View("/helloworld").ToString(); //Get the ViewResult as a string.
// {...} do something with the webpage string.
return Content(webpage); //Now return it as you normally would
```

Is it possible?

Comment: the exact duplicate question isn't about asp.net core, I was going to answer this question but since it is closed as duplicate I added my own aspnetcore specific answer to that question

Comment: but then again the OP maybe was incorrect to tag his question as asp.net-core, the code in the question does not look like asp.net core code